# Create AD Users from a client Computer (remotely)

Tags: python, vba, ms-access

Is there a simpler way to establish a connection to Active directory from a client computer? Ideally I would like to create AD users from an MS Access db on a client computer. The Client and DC Server are located locally. I have explored different ways to accomplish this using VBA and Python but never seem to establish a connection to our Active Directory even to pull simple user information. Do I need to install the LDAP on the sever or is there another way without installing anything on server. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Directory supports an LDAP dialect. You don't need to "install LDAP" to make LDAP requests or create users. You just need permission. If you can't even pull data, you're doing something wrong, and you need to fix that. Perhaps you could post some code?

To pull information from AD into Access using VBA, you can use ADO or LDAP or WMI objects, amongst others:

```
GetObject("ADO ...
or 
GetObject("LDAP ... 
or 
GetObject("WMI ...
```

To create new users in Access VBA, you could do something like

```
Set root = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE")

Set obj = GetObject("LDAP://CN=Users," & Root.Get("defaultNamingContext")) 

Set NewUser = obj.Create("User", "cn=" & strNewUser)
NewUser.Put "sAMAccountName", strNewUser
NewUser.Put "sn", strNewUser
NewUser.Put "displayName", strNewUser
NewUser.SetInfo

NewUser.SetPassword "password"
```